# Vue Native Router gives error not being used

Tags: html, vue-component, vue-router

So I am creating an app for a school project and I am trying to make a navigation screen.
I have a screen with 2 buttons and I am trying to make them work. If I click/press on the button I want to go to a diffrent screen.
I am new to this, this is the first time I am using Vue Native.

Current code:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <HelloWorld msg="CarnavalXL"/>
    <div id="nav">
      <button @press="goToParadeScreen" class="nav-button">Optochten</button>
      <button href="screens/Parades.vue" class="nav-button" title="Niews">Nieuws</button>
      <router-link to="Parades" class="nav-button">Parades</router-link>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'

export default {
  name: 'CarnavalXL',
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
    AppNavigator
  },
  props: {
    navigation: {
      type: Object
    }
  },
  methods: {
    goToPAradeScreen() {
      this.navigation.navigate("Parades");
    }
  }

}
import {
  createAppContainer,
  createStackNavigator,
} from "vue-native-router";
import Parades from "./Parades.vue";
this.navigation.navigate("Parades", {/* options go here */});
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Parades: Parades,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Parades',
  }
);
const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(StackNavigator);

</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left: 25vw;
  margin-right: 25vw;
}
.nav-button {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
padding: 100px 0px;
width: 20vw;
display: inline-block;
margin: 5px;
color: #fff;
font-size: 40px;
font-weight: 800;
}
</style>
```

I get the following error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/App.vue
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):

D:\carnavalxl\src\App.vue
  19:5  error  The "AppNavigator" component has been registered but not used  vue/no-unused-components

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

I followed the guide on the site of [Vue Native](https://vue-native.io/docs/vue-native-router.html)

I do not know what is going wrong here

Answer (score 0):

It's because your only importing the HelloWord component and not importing AppNavigator component. If you have a component called AppNavigator you have to import it like the HelleWorld like this:

import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'